# A broad singlet at 2.27 ppm?

Tags: synthesis, nmr-spectroscopy

I took the $\mathrm{^{1}H}$-NMR (CDCl3 solvent) of my product, 2,2-dimethoxy acetic acid. Below is what I see:

> $\delta \: \pu{4.862 ppm}$ (1H), $\delta \: \pu{3.521 ppm}$ (6.78H), **$\delta \: \pu{2.271 ppm}$ (5.39H)**

Peaks at $\delta \: \pu{4.862 ppm}$ and $\delta \: \pu{3.521 ppm}$ indicate my product I believe, but I cannot rationalise a peak at $\delta \: \pu{2.271 ppm}$.

I did dry my organic phase over $\ce{Na2SO4}$ so this cannot be water. I have never really seen a broad singlet in 2-3 ppm region. Does anyone have any idea what this would be? Would appreciate any thoughts&ideas.

Comment: Which solvents/reactants did you use in your synthesis?
You can find the shift of some impurities in various deuterated solvents here.

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.oprd.5b00417

Comment: Definitely can be water, and almost certainly is. How broad? Do you see 13C satellites? Add a drop of H2O and see if this peak increases and moves. Or change the temperature or field.

Comment: @The_Vinz I used diethyl ether

Comment: @long very broad. like I need to increase the resolution a LOT to see it. I will try the method

Comment: Water can be present in the nmr solvent, not necessarily your sample itself